# Get pattern text that is within search string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to do what I presume to be a simple regex query. In the example below, I'm trying to find all text between the word 'adverb', and 'verb'. The output I get is `'verb'`, I reckon that this is a result of the text 'verb' being in 'adverb'.

```
re.search(r'adverb.+noun|\bverb', 'adverb with text verb text from here on')
```

My question is how the heck do I get the text I require here? And as you can tell, I need to cater for multiple endstring words.

If it makes a difference, I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: why do you have `noun` in your regex? Remove it, along with the `|` and `\b` and capture the dot. I'd add a `?` just in case, and you get [this](http://www.regex101.com/r/zH9oU6).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex should be something like this:

*You can use `re.search()` ofcourse..*

```
import re
string = 'adverb with text verb text from here on'
print re.findall(r'adverb(.*?)verb', string)
```

And it prints out this:

```
# [' with text ']
```

**EDITED:**

If you want to get `noun` as well, use this:

```
import re
string = [
    'adverb with text verb text from here on',
    'adverb with text noun text from here on'
]
print [re.findall(r'adverb(.*?)(?:verb|noun)', s) for s in string]
```

And now you have:

```
# [[' with text '], [' with text ']]
```